# VBA to run python script. The VBA was executed but the python script did nothing

Tags: python, vba

I am trying to run a simple python code using VBA. The VBA ran but the expected result of the python code is not observed. I am using the yfinance library in the python code. I realised that if I do not use the yfinance library. I will be able to write the dataframe to the excel file successfully using the VBA. I am not sure why with yfinance library, the VBA failed. Appreciate any help!

Thanks and regards,
John

My VBA code

```
Sub RunPythonScript()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\jhuan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"""
    
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\jhuan\OneDrive\Full Stack trading app\test.py"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript



End Sub
```

My Python code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

tickerData = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
tickerBid = tickerData.info['bid']
#tickerBid = 1
x = pd.DataFrame({"A": [tickerBid]})
filepath = "C:/John Stock Ranking/test.xlsx"
x.to_excel(filepath)
```

Comment: `objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript`

Comment: Hi Mark,

There is no error message. Just that I do not see the data being printed in the excel.

Comment: Hi Justin,
tried that but still the same result.
thks

Comment: This sounds like it might be a thread issue.  If I have the workbook open and run a script from the command prompt to write a basic dataframe to a worksheet, I get `[Errorno 13] Permission denied:...`

Comment: As a side note, I have a y finance script here that allows for multiple tickers and date windows. https://github.com/MarkMoretto/finance/blob/master/data/y_finance.py

Comment: @John You know, you could also try creating a temp workbook and then importing that Excel worksheet into the main workbook.  That might be a workaround, though it won't be quite as simple as your initial script.